# Short story - Man and beautiful girl are space tourists who visit disasters in galaxies

Tags: story-identification, time-travel

Read this in early 1980s - man meets up with a beautiful girl with equally beautiful friends.  They are space tourists who visit disasters across galaxies and who are in town (San Francisco?) to await the catastrophe which is about to occur.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vintage_Season / https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Timescape_(1992_film)

Comment: @Richard That's what it sounds like to me too.

Comment: Sci Fi enthusiast, is it possible that your "space tourists who visit disasters across galaxies" were actually "time tourists who visit disasters across centuries"?

Comment: Thank you so much - I think that's it ... will track it down through the archives.

Comment: @ScFienthusiast, if this is correct, please be sure to "accept" the answer by clicking the check mark icon near the top left of it. This is important for improving the quality of site statistics and for letting the moderators perform proper duplicate management. Welcome to the site!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Story about time traveling tourists who come back to witness human tragedies](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/190821/story-about-time-traveling-tourists-who-come-back-to-witness-human-tragedies)

Comment: It seems a little premature to close this as a dupe. The OP has posted that the proposed dupe **may** be the answer, but has yet to confirm.

Comment: And, while the OP hasn't been on site for more than two years, without a confirmation, we don't clkose story-id questions as dupes.

Comment: Not a million miles away from _Doctor Who_ to be honest.

Comment: possibly the same as https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/190821/story-about-time-traveling-tourists-who-come-back-to-witness-human-tragedies (which is newer but has an accepted answer)

Answer (score 11):

(Since this remains inexplicably without a formal answer despite the comments above, I can only assume that the giants here have intentionally left it for others.)

There is a very good chance that this is a slightly misremembered version of "Vintage Season" by Henry Kuttner and C. L. Moore. Originally published in the September 1946 issue of *Astounding Science Fiction* magazine (under the name "Lawrence O'Donnell"), and [collected numerous times since then](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?59665), this story's plot concerns time-traveling tourists who visit the scenes of great catastrophes in (their) past.

The travelers are uniformly depicted as attractive. Per the plot summary from Wikipedia (bold mine):

> The story is set in an unnamed American city at about the time of
> publication. There are **several mentions of how beautiful the weather
> is**.
>
> Oliver Wilson is renting an old mansion to three vacationers for the
> month of May. He wants to get rid of them so he can sell the house to
> someone who has offered him three times its value, provided the buyer
> can move in during May. His fiancée, Sue, insists that he arrange for
> them to leave, so that he can sell the house, giving them enough money
> for their impending marriage.
>
> The tenants are a man, Omerie Sancisco, and two women, Klia and Kleph
> **Sancisco**. They **fascinate Oliver with the perfection of their
> appearance** and manners, their strange connoisseur's attitude to
> everything, and their secretiveness about their origin and about their
> insistence on that house at that time. Oliver's half-hearted attempts
> to evict them founder when he becomes attracted to Kleph. The mystery
> deepens with remarks she lets slip, with the unspectacular but
> advanced technology of things she has in her room—including a recorded
> "symphonia" that engages all the senses with imagery of historical
> disasters—and with the appearance of the would-be buyers, a couple
> from the same country...
>
> At the end of May, more time travelers visit the house. **A meteorite
> lands nearby, destroying buildings and starting fires—the "spectacle"
> that the time travelers wanted to end their visit with.** Oliver's house
> survives, as the visitors had already known it would.

It seems likely that the name "Sancisco" (plus references to the great weather) is what makes you think it might have been set in San Francisco.

The entire story can be read online at [archive.org](https://archive.org/stream/Astounding_v38n01_1946-09_cape1736#page/n54/mode/2up), starting on page 54 of the digitized issue.

Obviously, the real credit here goes to Richard, who IDed this first in comments, and who points out that it has also been used as the basis for [a movie](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0104362/?ref_=fn_al_tt_1). As user14111 implies, the story is a great match for your description if one allows for time travelers instead of space travelers.

Comment: Good answer. I added info about the pen name because that byline was retained in some anthologies, and people looking for it should know that it's the same story. As usual, roll back if you don't like. Didn't know Frisco was famous for its great weather. Maybe compared with Saskatchewan or Mali.

Comment: "Vintage Season" was dramatized on *Sci-Fi Radio* and is available at the [Internet Archive](https://archive.org/details/Sci-fiRadio).