# A short story about time travelers who love to attend to disasters

Tags: story-identification, time-travel

I read this short story (or perhaps just long enough to be a novelette) at least 20 years ago but I think it is much older (see below why). In French, in a collection but it was clearly a translation from English.

The story is told from the POV of a character who is stuck in his time. At the beginning he has no idea that time travel even exists. Nor does the reader. This realisation comes later for both. He is fascinated by these "tourists", well dressed, obviously very well educated, who keep talking about disasters  (Pompei? Lisbon earthquake? Great fire of London?) But they don't actually mention that they were personally present, so he cannot **conclude** they are "time-travelling disaster tourists". But he starts having doubts. One particularly beautiful woman flirts with him. At some point she makes a slip: she is humming a song. The POV character knows how old this song is. But the woman says that just a month (or a week?) before she was present when the song was first sung.

So he understands everything. And he wonders, what disaster are they waiting for? Then he notices something: all of them have a small scar on the arm. A scar looking like the one that I am one of a very small percentage of people to have now: a scar from a smallpox vaccination.

So the book was written at a time when vaccinations left scars. Such scars disappeared even long before they stopped injecting against smallpox! An old book indeed!

Anyway the POV character understands that an epidemics is going to happen and that the tourists got immunity. But not himself nor anyone of his time....

Comment: See also https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/190821/28516

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This is [Vintage Season](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vintage_Season) by Henry Kuttner and C. L. Moore, originally published as by Lawrence O'Donnell.

> Hearing Kleph sing "Come hider, love, to me" from the Prologue to
> Chaucer's Canterbury Tales, Oliver realizes that she and her friends
> are time travelers from the future. He traps Kleph into admitting they
> are visiting the most perfect seasons in history, such as a fall in
> the late 14th century in Canterbury. Oliver happens to see a healed
> scar on her arm, which she hastens to cover and admits with obvious
> shame that it is an inoculation; the reason for her shame will become
> clear only at the end.

Comment: Ninja'd, well done. https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?59665

Comment: @OrganicMarble - I also spent ten minutes making myself an omelette before answering, so you've really only got yourself to blame

Comment: Naturally! This seems to be the master question https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/190821/28516

Comment: Yes ! The name "Kleph" sounds familiar.